# python script doesn't execute when calling it from shell

Tags: python, linux, tcsh

I have a python 3 program in file `foo` the file has execution permissions, and the first line of the script is

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

When I run the file from python directly, i.e:

```
/usr/bin/python3 foo 3 boo
```

Everything runs perfectly well, but when I try to run the program by calling the file name I get:

```
foo 3 boo
foo: Command not found.
```

Even when specifying the relative or full path to the script I get the same response.

```
./foo 3 boo
./foo: Command not found.

/full/path/to/the/file/foo 3 boo
/full/path/to/the/file/foo: Command not found.
```

**Some more info that was requested:**

```
head -2 foo
#!/usr/bin/python3

which python3
/usr/bin/python3
```

Working from tcsh, where is the problem?

I'm working on a remote university computer through ssh, could it be the case that the sysadmins somehow prevent this?

Comment: Have you made your script executable?

Comment: @Anton, yes I did

Comment: @Anton read carefully the question. He explicitly said it have.

Comment: @RaoslawSzamszur Yep, my bad. And the answers below are correct

Comment: @SIMEL, can you do show the `head -2 foo` & `which python` output from terminal?

Comment: @pygo see edit.

Comment: @SIMEL maybe this is issue with this tcsh shell. Can you run script of yours from bash to confirm?

Comment: @SIMEL, as i see all consideration you already met this is just a problem of  `tcsh`  shell try running like  `tcsh -c ./foo.py` , it will work.

Comment: Maybe your sysadmin do not allow to execute code in the partition where your ssh home is located

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the absolute path of the script. Try

```
./foo 3 boo
```

while in the same directory as the script. Otherwise, the shell will only look in your `PATH` for something named `foo`, which doesn't exist.

Comment: I get the same response, even when stating the full path to the script, I get the same response.

Answer (score 0):

You must give the path to the file

`./foo`

If you just call "foo", the shell will look in the environment variable $PATH the folder that contains the "foo" binary, and he will not find it ...

Answer (score 0):

I'm using python3, just an example illustration..

Just a test script ..

```
$ cat test.py
#!/python/v3.6.1/bin/python3
import os
print(os.system("ls"))

$ which python3
/python/v3.6.1/bin/python3
```

Permission to make it executable.. i'm have doubt if the script `foo` is executable in your case..

```
$ chmod +x test.py
```

Test Run..

```
$ ./test.py
a.py     Backup     File_Write_Method  NWK-old              Python_aritsTest  Python_Ftp   Python_Mail     Python_Primer  test.py
argpass  BASH       Network_DeOps      Python-3.6.3         Python_Dump       Python_FTP   Python_Panda    readme_python  tmp
awk.sh   dnspython  nslookup           Python-3.6.3.tar.xz  Python_excep      Python_ldap  Python_Parsers  Regular_Expr   tt.csv
0
```

**It might be shell problem as i reproduced the tcsh shell & it fails to run..**

> ```
> $ tcsh
> $ ./test
> ./test: Command not found.
> ```

but it runs , when i run it like below..

```
tcsh -c ./test.py
```

Comment: @wpercy, thats weird :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your script is executable and you have python3 in /usr/bin/python3. I think you are trying to run your script from a partition mounted with the noexec argument to check if it is the problem you should run:

```
mount | grep <partition> | grep noexec
```

If I'm right you can just mount the partition with the exec option or move your script elsewhere.